# How to bundle Java App to associated .desktop file in Gnome/Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx, gnome

Sorry, bu I didn't find any solution yet. I have an executable jar file (JavaFx based app) which I can easy start from bash:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I want this app to start from a side panel in Ubuntu, so I'm creating .desktop file and place it in /usr/share/applications directory. And it works out, I see my app in apps list, mark it as Favorite and it appears in the side-panel ready for quick-access. But when I run it Gnome creates another associated .desktop file (temporary) and put a dot under that instead of using mine.

So, how to bundle my app with .desktop file ? So, when I run my app I want Gnome to put a dot under the right .desktop file (from which I run it!!). For example, when running Visual Code or Intellij Idea I have a dot under them, even if I do it from bash. Really, I search for idea.desktop file, see which executable it use, go to that executable and just run it from bash and it links with idea's icon!

```
/snap/bin/intellij-idea-ultimate
```

Of course, I'm not sure if it's usual executable, but anyway how does it work ? I thought that the .desktop file is responsible for this linkage, but if I run executable from bash and gnome puts a dot under the right icon without need to be started from this icon...

[image]

Comment: @NomadMaker and how is it applicable to my problem ?

Comment: First of all there is a nice gradle plugin that builds scripts that run your application, its called application plugin.

Comment: Further there should be no difference in building a desktop file for a java app. Just use the java execuable and give it the -jar your.jar argument. https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en read this tells you how to create one.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a terminal
2. run : xprop WM_CLASS
3. click on your application window
4. copy one of the string generated in the terminal
5. add it to your .desktop file. The key is "StartupWMClass". So it looks something like StartupWMClass="the string you copied earlier.

That should do it.

For example this is how my firefox .desktop looks like

```
 [Desktop Entry]
...
    StartupWMClass=Firefox
    StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   [Desktop Entry]
   ....
   StartupWMClass=<fully qualified Application class name>
```

Example:

```
   [Desktop Entry]
   ....
   StartupWMClass=org.mycompany.app.Application
```